# Unity3d external camera frame rate

Tags: input, camera, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I am working on a live augmented reality application. So far I have worked on many AR-Applications for mobile devices. 
Now I have to get the video signal from a Panasonic P2. The camera is an European version. I catch the signal with a AJA io HD Box, witch is connected by firewire to a MacPro. So far everything works great - just not in Unity. 
When I start the preview in Unity the framebuffer of the AJA ControlPanel jumps to a frame-rate of 59.94 fps. I guess because of a preference on unity. Because of the European version of the camera I can not switch to 59,94fps or 29,47fps. 
I checked all settings in Unity, but couldn't find anything...

Is there any possibility to change the frame-rate unity captures from an external camera?

Comment: You should include some code.  Are you using a WebcamTexture, are you polling the camera via an IP address, are you loading data through a custom 3rd party API, etc.

Comment: I am currently using the string SDK. So far I did not code anything. First I have to get a working camera capture.

Comment: w/o code it's impossible to diagnose the problem.  As far as I know though Unity doesn't have an explicit frame rate setting.  According to the String [package](http://www.poweredbystring.com/product): "Frame rate limited only by camera hardware", so it sounds like String just polls your digital camera as fast as it can.

Answer (score 0):

If you're polling the camera from Unity's Update() function then you will be under the influence of Vsync, which limits frame processing to 60 FPS.

You can switch off Vsync by going to [Edit > Project Settings > Quality](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html) and then setting the option Vsync Count to "*don't sync*".